# Save query in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model `PPTLcode`

```
class PPTLcode(models.Model): # many to one relationship with PPTLconfig
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    pconf = models.ForeignKey('PPTLconfig', related_name= 'codes')
```

I've a list of codes. I want to save each code in the list with reference to only one `pconf`.  I can use an iteration for doing this. Just curious to know, whether there's a one line solution for it?

Currently I'm doing like this:-

```
for code in code_list:
    obj = PPTLcode(code=code, pconf=pconf_obj)
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to to save new objects in one query:

```
obj_list = []
for code in code_list:
    obj_list.append(PPTLcode(code = code, pconf = pconf_obj))
PPTLcode.objects.bulk_create(obj_list)
```

Or a one line solution:

```
PPTLcode.objects.bulk_create([PPTLcode(code=code, pconf=pconf_obj) for code in code_list])
```

Note: `bulk_create` is avaliable in django >= 1.4

Comment: what about `[PPTLcode(code=code, pconf=pconf_obj).save() for code in code_list]`

Comment: @suhail this will create query for every `save()` call, whereas `bulk_create` will do only one query for saving entire list of objects.